# In what contexts is the word "iff" actually used?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

When I took a proofwriting class, I was told that it was not appropriate for formal mathematical writing to abbreviate "if and only if" as *iff*. I've heard *iff* called "mathematical slang". And, indeed, I have never seen it used in a formal proof -- really only ever in online discussions of mathematics, as on StackExchange.

But it's apparently widespread enough to make it into general-purpose dictionaries. It doesn't really work in speech, so if it's not used in mathematical writing, where *is* it used?

Comment: It is used widely in mathematical proofs.

Comment: Some quick situations that come to mind are during presentations (when someone's writing on a board, e.g.) or informal chat discussions.

Comment: It is often used and is widely accepted and saves time while writing answers

Comment: This sounds like personal preference and nitpickyness of editors.  There is little difference to me between the question of using "iff" versus "if and only if" and the question of using "won't" versus "will not."  I had some high school writing teachers who insisted that no contractions with apostrophes were to be used in work we handed in.  Once leaving that class however, I continue to see contractions used in many contexts including professional ones.

Comment: If your tutor doesn't like it, don't use it in the work you do for them. Otherwise it is well-understood and as precise as the longer expression it abbreviates, so there is no mathematical or logical loss in using it. The objection seems to me to be sociological rather than mathematical.

Comment: As for "*It doesn't really work in speech*"... despite it being spelled "iff" I still pronounce it as "if and only if" personally.

Comment: Imho it shouldn’t be used in proofs to be read by another person, because it can easily be misread as *if*. Its not a question of formality, it is a question of service to the reader.

Comment: Well, we had a [related dicussion on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30468/537079) before.

Comment: @JMoravitz That is, in fact, the pronunciation given in Merriam Webster's dictionary, which makes it the only word in English that has more syllables than letters.

Comment: I cannot say that I can recall ever having seen "iff" in a research level publication, and the only books in which I've seen it used are elementary texts where the notation "iff" is being defined (note:  this doesn't mean that "iff" doesn't appear in publications or more advanced texts, only that I cannot recall seeing it in this context).  On the other hand, the word(?) is frequently used in informal contexts, such as lecture notes.  It is a useful shorthand in that setting, but my preference is to see it expanded in more formal contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The word "iff" is a shortcut for "if and only if". As such, it has the same status as "wlog" (without loss of generality), w.r.t. (with respect to) and "s.t." (such that). As these three examples, it is mostly used in one of the following circumstances:

1. During a lecture on a blackboard, when time is limited.
2. During a lecture using slides, when time and space are limited.
3. When you take handwritten notes, again to save time and space.

**P.S**. When I prepared this answer, I was almost sure to find some arguments in Halmos' paper [1], my favourite reference on mathematical writing. To my surprise, I found no mention of "iff" in [1], but I later realized that the neologism "iff" has been popularized by Halmos, who could then hardly give a strong opinion on his own creation... Quoting Halmos [2, p. 403]:

> My most nearly immortal contributions are an abbreviation and a
>   typographical symbol. I invented "iff", for "if and only if"- but I
>   could never believe that I was really its first inventor. I am quite
>   prepared to believe that it existed before me, but I don't know that
>   it did, and my invention (re-invention'1) of it is what spread it
>   through the mathematical world.

[1] Paul R. Halmos, [How to write mathematics](http://www.di.ens.fr/~bouillar/Stages/Halmos-How-To-Write.pdf). Enseign. Math. (2) 16 (1970), 123--152.

[2] Paul R. Halmos, *I want to be a mathematician. An automathography.* Springer-Verlag, New York, 1985. xvi + 421 pp. ISBN: 0-387-96078-3